# Operand type clash: <type> is incompatible with <type> from TSQL union select

Tags: t-sql

Running an sql query like

```
select a, b 
from ab
union all
select b, a
from ba
```

generates errors like:

```
{"Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date\r\n Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with int"}
{"Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with bit\r\nOperand type clash: ntext is incompatible with bit"}
{"Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with int\r\nOperand type clash: ntext is incompatible with int"}
```

etc..

Comment: Why are you still using `ntext`? It's been deprecated for **16 years**.

Comment: I didn't create the db or the tables, it is an existing project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to tsql and I didn't know that the columns in both select statements should be in the same order.  Like this:

```
select a, b 
from ab
union all
select a, b
from ba
```

I thought sql server would automatically associate the columns because of the names, but I was wrong.  I spent hours troubleshooting this and searching for the above error and no results regarding Union All needing to have columns in correct order.  I didn't even know to add the term `Union` to my search because I didn't think it had anything to do with my issue. So I'm adding this to hopefully save someone else.